# Is it safe to init c++ class with pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

For example, I have a constructor like

```
myClass(const char* name);
```

Can it be like

```
myClass(const char* name);
{
  someInnerField = name;
}
```

or I should copy input string to inner field by value?

Comment: It really depends on how your class is supposed to deal with the object pointed at by the pointer. First you have to decide who owns it.

Comment: The question is: Do you want to share the string with other objects or not?

Comment: Object will be needed all the lifetime of instance of the class, so I don't want it to be modified or released outside the class. Also, input string can be modified anywhere else.

Comment: But the question is, will it be needed *after* a `myClass` object dies (who owns the object pointed at)? And does `myClass` need to refer to an object, or is it OK for it to have a copy of it? (value or reference semantics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's safe is:

```
std::string someInnerField;
myClass(const std::string& name) : someInnerField(name)
{
}
```

Your version could fail if the class destroys the memory its member points to (and you still use it outside the scope of the class) or if the memory is destroyed outside the class (and you continue to use it inside).

Comment: (For the OP, this syntax is called an "initialization list", in case it's foreign)

Comment: Doesn't destroying memory pointed to by a const pointer go against the very idea of `const`, meaning the area pointed to will not be modified in any way?

Comment: @SF. no & it's not a const pointer, but a pointer to const char.

Comment: There's no problem with the parameter being `char const*`; although `std::string` is usually preferable, there are cases where you might more or less expect a `char const*`.  The essential thing is that the member be a `std::string`.

Comment: @JamesKanze the question is whether it's safe. And I can think of multiple situations where this would crash and burn.

Comment: @Luchian: Yes, meaning the area pointed to will not be changed. It's hard to think of a change bigger than utter deletion.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore (re safe): If `someInnerField` is a `std::string`, then this IS safe (unless you're initializing with invalid pointer), because at the time of initialization it will create a copy. Now if `someInnerField` is `const char*` you must believe `name` was truly `const char*` from the very beginning, and not a `char*` cast to const later, or a member of some volatile structure that can be unloaded at runtime.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Can you?  I can't think of one.

Comment: @JamesKanze ok, that's true, because the current syntax restricts the member to be a `std::string` (or something that makes a copy of the parameter).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're doing with the class, and the types of strings
which are valid on input.  Generally (almost always, in fact), the class
should use `std::string` as a member, in which case, it's perfectly
safe.  Otherwise, there are a very few instances where it makes sense to
restrict the argument to string literals (or some other known source of
data with a static lifetime), in which case, you can get away with just
saving the pointer.  (But this is very, very fragile.  I'd avoid it, and
still use `std::string`.)

Answer (score 0):

Is safe as long as you are sure that the argumet will not be a pointer to a memory zone that could be deleted by somebody else.
But to be sure every time when you deal with pointers you can check there validity before usage otherwise you risk an memory exception.

Comment: Unfortunately checking for validity in this case won't work. Some outside function performs `delete(name) ; name=NULL` but   `someInnerField` still points to the deallocated area without any informations about its validity.

Comment: There's no way you can check the validity.

Comment: the information about validity is name == null so beffore using it you can do  if (someInnerField != NULL) {do something} else {print error}

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. Please Use std::string, Or you can use the function of "strcpy" or "memcpy" if "char*"。